# Apt-get broken when running sudo apt-get install -f (No solution on the duplicates works)

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm currently get an error when running any apt-get install comands

simillar to:
[Broken apt, can't update libglvnd due to unmet dependencies (Nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077595/broken-apt-cant-update-libglvnd-due-to-unmet-dependencies-nvidia)
and the duplicate listed there.
Neither methoded named there seems to work.

I have simmilar problems to the comments to the last sollution named by nilesh_101

Output to `sudo apt-get install -f` is the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gstreamer1.0-nice libdee-1.0-4 libfarstream-0.2-5 libgadu3 libgirara-gtk3-3 libgtkspell0
  libllvm6.0:i386 libmeanwhile1 libmessaging-menu0 libprotobuf-c1 libpurple-bin libpurple0 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity9 libzephyr4 linux-headers-4.15.0-65
  linux-headers-4.15.0-65-generic linux-image-4.15.0-65-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-65-generic pidgin-data python-attr python-automat python-click python-colorama
  python-constantly python-hyperlink python-incremental python-lzma python-pam python-parsley python-pyasn1 python-pyasn1-modules python-serial python-service-identity python-twisted python-twisted-bin
  python-twisted-core python-txsocksx python-zope.interface
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libglvnd-core-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libglvnd-core-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/153 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2.291 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 504288 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglvnd-core-dev_1.2.0-1~b~padoka0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglvnd-core-dev:amd64 (1.2.0-1~b~padoka0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-core-dev_1.2.0-1~b~padoka0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/EGL/egl.h', which is also in package libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 1:19.3~git191017152900.82f18b7~b~padoka0
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-core-dev_1.2.0-1~b~padoka0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is there anybody who sloved this at this point?

Comment: `Unpacking libglvnd-core-dev:amd64 (1.2.0-1~b~padoka0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd-core-dev_1.2.0-1~b~padoka0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/EGL/egl.h', which is also in package libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 1:19.3~git191017152900.82f18b7~b~padoka0`. Read your output carefully: You cannot have both of those packages installed at the same time. Pick one, uninstall the other.

Comment: You should contact the ppa owner about this. There are actually around 16 conflicting files, some are the exact same content wise, some aren't. Note that libegl1-mesa-dev depends on libglvnd-dev which depends on libglvnd-core-dev so above comment is wrong..(- you could use a --force-overwrite option but I'd let ppa maintainer deal with this.

Comment: The force overwrite doesn't seem to work since I don't know how to get the right .deb file

and how do I find out which ppa is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After doing further reasarch on the exact .deb file I found another one having trouble with it here: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187545/dpkg-error-conflict-while-installing-packages/1189151`
This together with the information of doug helped me to figuer out that the fault was in the following `ppa: https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa`

removing this helped.